# Bootstrap Center a Div in the Middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div here which contains 3 dropdowns:

```
<div class="text-center container">
       <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="make" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Subject
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="makein">
                    <li>bmw</li>
                    <li>mercedes</li>
                    <li>mazda</li>
                    <li>ford</li>
                    <li>lada</li>
                    <li>audi</li>
                    <li>skoda</li>
                    <li>fiat</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="year" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Year
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="yearin">
                    <li>2016</li>
                    <li>2015</li>
                    <li>2014</li>
                    <li>2013</li>
                    <li>2012</li>
                    <li>2011</li>
                    <li>2010</li>
                    <li>2009</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="level" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Level
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="levelin">
                    <li>luxury</li>
                    <li>ordinary</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
      </div>
```

I use the following to center the div in the middle of the screen centered:

```
.container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;

}

.dropdown{
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

It also aligns my drop downs horizontally.

I locate my div in the middle of the screen using this custom css. I am wondering if there is a way to avoid using the custom css and do this same thing just purely using Bootstrap.

My aim is:
1: Locate the `container` in the center in the middle of the page.
2: Horizontally align the dropdowns.

Comment: Isn't `container` centered by default? There's no need to redefine `container` in your CSS.

Comment: I need it in the middle of the page

Comment: please share your full html file, header included...

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap shipped with  `container` and `text-center` classes then why you are defining your own `container` class? Just include bootstrap files properly in your code and no need for this custom CSS.

`text-center` class will align your drop down in middle of screen and `container` class has fixed width with auto margin. Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf6ckatv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result , use below CSS to container

```
.container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top:20%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LkoLGw

Answer (score 0):

There are no way in bootstrap to locate div in the middle of the screen.
you may check below custom css code:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 45%;
}
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
```